# Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 596

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, fatal-error

Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Getting fatal error while setup magento project on localhost.
Localhost config:
PHP 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11
apache

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Increasing max_nesting_level value

Edit the php.ini file and search for [xdebug]. You should find a block containing the xdebug extension location and settings.

See if there is already an entry xdebug.max_nesting_level, if not, just add it at the end of the block with a higher value than 100:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=256
```

Try increasing it if 256 is not sufficient.

**Taken from:** http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/troubleshooting/max-nesting-level

Comment: No Luck. Please, suggest more.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, but for Magento you need to increase it a lot. Try 1500 or higher.